# Missing Site Pages Library

Tags: sharepoint-online, site, modern-pages, modern-team-site

Overnight site pages disappeared from one of my SharePoint Online team sites, checked site features and the recycling bin and I am not seeing them anywhere.

Any recommendations on where to look for them? They are missing from Site Contents and when attempting to go them directly I am getting a page not found

[image]

Comment: If you navigate to `/SitePages/Forms/ByAuthor.aspx` for the team site, does the directory still exist?

Comment: Directory does not exist :-(

Comment: That would seem to indicate that the Site Pages directory was deleted (probably by someone that didn't know what the Library was). If you have auditing enabled you can check your reports to see who deleted it.

Comment: I would also check the site recycling bin and Secondary recycling bin.

Comment: Have already checked both recycling bins, nothing to be found there. Escalating this to Microsoft support. I don't believe I have auditing turned on, does it need to be on each site level or is this a site collection level?

Comment: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/configure-audit-settings-for-a-site-collection-a9920c97-38c0-44f2-8bcb-4cf1e2ae22d2